# Why did my CountDownTimer not stop in onBackPressed()?

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

My Countdown timer is working fine but when i use back press during running state of the time,my countdown timer did not stopped. I have tried everything as follows but none of them is able to stop the countdown timer from running in the background. 
After searching the forum an applying the results from it to my project I am unable to figure out whats fault in my code. Please anyone hep me out and i shall be very thankful.

```
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (countDownTimer != null) {
        countDownTimer.cancel();

    }
    super.onDestroy();
   finish();

}


@Override
protected void onPause() {


    if (countDownTimer!=null) {
        countDownTimer.cancel();

    }
    super.onPause();
    finish();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {


    if (countDownTimer!=null) {
        countDownTimer.cancel();

    }
    super.onStop();
    finish();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {


    if (countDownTimer!=null) {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();

}
```

My full Edited code

```
public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final long COUNTDOWN_IN_MILLIS = 30000 ;

List<Questions> mQuestions;
int score = 0;
int qid = 0;
Questions currentQ;
TextView txtQuestions, textViewCountDown;
RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc;
Button btnNext;
private QuestionsViewModel questionsViewModel;
private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
private LinearLayout linearLayout;

private ColorStateList textColorDefaultCd;
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private long timeLeftInMillis;
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        takeAction();

    }
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    textViewCountDown = findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.profileLoadingScreen);
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearView);
    textColorDefaultCd = textViewCountDown.getTextColors();


    fetchQuestions();

    questionsViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(QuizActivity.this).get(QuestionsViewModel.class);

    questionsViewModel.getAllQuestions().observe(this, new Observer<List<Questions>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Questions> words) {
            // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
            mQuestions = words;
            //Collections.shuffle(mQuestions);
            Collections.addAll(mQuestions);

        }
    });

}



private void fetchQuestions() {


    DataServiceGenerator dataServiceGenerator = new DataServiceGenerator();

    Service service = DataServiceGenerator.createService(Service.class);

    Call<List<QuestionsModel>> call = service.getQuestions();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<QuestionsModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<QuestionsModel>> call, Response<List<QuestionsModel>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){

                if (response != null){
                    List<QuestionsModel> questionsModelList = response.body();

                    for (int i = 0; i < questionsModelList.size(); i++){
                        String question = questionsModelList.get(i).getQuestion();
                        String answer = questionsModelList.get(i).getAnswer();
                        String opta = questionsModelList.get(i).getOpta();
                        String optb = questionsModelList.get(i).getOptb();
                        String optc = questionsModelList.get(i).getOptc();

                        Questions questions = new Questions(question, answer, opta, optb, optc);

                        questionsViewModel.insert(questions);
                    }

                    handler = new Handler();//add this
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);

          /*  Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            takeAction();

                        }
                    }, 3000);*/




                }

            }else{

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<QuestionsModel>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

}

private void setQuestionView()
{
    txtQuestions.setText(currentQ.getQuestion());
    rda.setText(currentQ.getOptA());
    rdb.setText(currentQ.getOptB());
    rdc.setText(currentQ.getOptC());
    qid++;


}

private void startCountDown() {
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
            updateCountDownText();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timeLeftInMillis = 0;
            updateCountDownText();
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
            intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }.start();
}

private void updateCountDownText() {
    int minutes = (int) (timeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
    int seconds = (int) (timeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;

    String timeFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);

    textViewCountDown.setText(timeFormatted);

    if (timeLeftInMillis < 10000) {
        textViewCountDown.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    } else {
        textViewCountDown.setTextColor(textColorDefaultCd);
    }
}



private void takeAction() {
    relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    textViewCountDown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    timeLeftInMillis = COUNTDOWN_IN_MILLIS;
    startCountDown();



    currentQ = mQuestions.get(qid);
    txtQuestions = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    rda=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    rdb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    rdc=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    btnNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    setQuestionView();
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioGroup grp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

            if (grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please Select an Answer",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return;

            }else{
               // countDownTimer.cancel();

            }

            RadioButton answer=(RadioButton)findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

            grp.clearCheck();
            //Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getANSWER()+" "+answer.getText());

            if(currentQ.getAnswer().equals(answer.getText()))
            {
                score++;
                Log.d("score", "Your score"+score);
            }else{

            }
            if(qid<10){
                currentQ=mQuestions.get(qid);
                setQuestionView();
            }else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(handler!=null){
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
    if (countDownTimer != null) {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        countDownTimer = null;

    }
    finish();

}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
   if(handler!=null){
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }

    if (countDownTimer!=null) {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        countDownTimer = null;

    }
    finish();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(handler!=null){
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
    if (countDownTimer!=null) {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        countDownTimer = null;

    }
    finish();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(handler!=null){
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
    if (countDownTimer!=null) {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        countDownTimer = null;
    }
    finish();
}
```

}

Comment: Please post the full code here so that its easy to debug the cause

Comment: why are you writing this - MyActivity.this.finish();?

Comment: Sir i have tried everything, even just writhing this.finish(); and also just finish(); but nothing is happening why? Sir @AkashDubey

Comment: debug and check is your if statement working or not.

Comment: Show the code how do u initialize it ? Also don't need to write `MyActivity.this.finish();` it will be finished while you pressing back press

Comment: Please post all your code,I've writed a TimerCount demo and it start fine cancel fine too.

Comment: @KatrinaPathak there is no need to write anything like that, onBackPress() will automatically do finish your activity

Comment: call super.onBackpressed(); in first line

Comment: I have updated my full code, Please Sir/madam  have a look. I have tried everything  and nothing is working for me.

Comment: how you figure out your countDownTimer  don't stop ?

Comment: Everything is working fine if i dont skip my question or dont backpress it while running the quiz but if i backpress it then my current activity finish but the timer is running in the background and when the timer stops it shows the  result activity @Radesh

Comment: Sir if i remove if (countDownTimer!=null) then the app crash because countdown timer has got  a null value. @Piyush

Comment: Yes that means your code seems right. Now you need to debug in `onFinish()` method and check does it call proper? Because if it calls then you don't need to cancel in `onDestroy` and `onBackPress()` because that activity will be finished already. Also further cancel count down time before start activity in `onFinish()` method.

Comment: Yes Sir code is working fine if i dont backpress it and okay sir just now i will give a try and let you know @Piyush

Comment: Then why are you overriding it? Because it itself finish the activity. When activity finish, the destroy method will be called and your timer will be cancelled as you wrote a code in that method.

Comment: remove  super.onBackPressed();

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {


    if (countDownTimer!=null) {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        countDownTimer = null;
    }
    finish();

}
```

**Update**

you use handler after 3 seconds and i don't know why

```
         Handler handler = new Handler();
         handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 takeAction();
                }
         }, 3000);
```

try to crate handler and runnable in global like this

```
private long timeLeftInMillis;
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 takeAction();
                }
         }
```

And then in `onResponse()` use it

```
 handler = new Handler();//add this
 handler.postDelayed(runnable,3000);
```

And finally in your `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`

```
if(hacdler!=null){
    hacdler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
}
```

Comment: No Sir it is not working without using  super.onBackPressed(); @Radesh

Comment: did you try that?

Comment: and what happened?

Comment: Nothing happened Sir, same problem ,when i backpress while loading the progress bar then current activity finishes but the countdown time is running at the background and after 30 sec it shows my result screen. Everything is working  fine for me in my code if i dont backpress it, but in case if i backpress after certain attempt of the question then timer dont stop and it still runs in the background and shows the result activity when it finish the time. @Radesh

Comment: you mean when you fetch questions you click on back this happened?

Comment: Yes Sir, this happens if i backpress at any point ,while fetching questions or even after getting all the questions or even after attempting some questions @Radesh

Comment: Sir, Not working  by creating handler and runnable in global and showing error 'boolean android.os.Handler.postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,long)' on a null object reference @Radesh

Comment: @KatrinaPathak oh sorry . miss something . check edited code

Comment: Sir you are great, i think it worked but sir with some new problems arrived ,i.e if sir before fully fetching the questions if i backpress then app crash and i have posted the crash report in the answer section. Sir please do have a look and sir you will not imagine,how much you have helped me.Thanks Again @Radesh

Comment: Sir, i think i have arrived to the same problem again as before, don't know what happened but it seems it is not working again and yesterday i tried very hard to figure out my problem but unable to find out and i have did as you said but nothing happened.@Radesh

Comment: Sir i have edited the code as per your request but none of them is working.@Radesh